# Activating jQuery Lazy Line Painter when in viewport

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, lazy-loading, viewport

I'm building a site were I'm using javascript and CSS3 animation to to load in a bunch of elements when they're in the viewport. However part of the site relies on the jQuery plugin lazylinepainter.info - The plugin itself animates onLoad/draws itself butthe animation is further down the page so it's already finished by the time the user has scrolled to it.

Is there a way of activating the animation/plugin when it's in the viewport only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the element is visible when the user scrolls, if so, perform the animation. Perhaps this thread will be able to help you.

[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)